Flatten one depth of list
I have a list nested inside another with a depth of 3.
[
  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
]

After using List.flatten/1 my result is
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

I want to flatten it in the same way below, while still keeping the same order of the elements inside intact.
[
  [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]
]

I wanted to know if there's a way to do that using any of Elixir's defined functions, I looked up the Elixir docs but wasn't able to find a way to do that without flattening the entire list.

So you just want to append together each of the top-level elements?

@ScottHunter what do you mean by top-level elements?

In this case, [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] and  [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]].

@ScottHunter yes that's correct

Just use Enum.concat/1:
Enum.concat([
  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
  [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
])

returns
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]


You also can use Enum.flat_map/1
iex> [
...>   [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]],
...>   [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
...> ] |> Enum.flat_map(fn x -> x end)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]


For the sake of completeness, here is another solution.
iex||1 ▶ Enum.reduce(input, &++/2)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

